# Why `this` returns Empty object when Compiled on regular IDE(like visual studio code)?

Tags: javascript, object, this

In Browser window, when I log `this` in window context it gives me output: Window object.
But here, In normal IDE(like visual studio code) when I compile it, gives me an empty object. why? And How this happens?

```
  console.log(this)  // in browsers output: window
// In IDE, output: {}

function test(){
    return this
}

console.log(test())  // output is global  // Why not empty
```

Main question is why `this` return me an empty object, when I run on Normal IDE?Thanks for your answers.

Comment: In IDE, it run on your machine by Node.js. It's a different runtime than in browser.

Comment: How are you running this in your IDE? Can you give some steps for this ?

Comment: step(1.) open command poallete...... step( 2.)using command `cd` entere the path of your js file, after you reach your file.....step (3.)enter `node abc.js`   (where abc is  name of your js file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refres to global scope in `console.log(this)`. In case of browser, it is `window`, in case of nodejs it is `Global` object. In case of vs code, they have empty object as global object as they can't afford to implement browser or nodejs global object apis and properties. As it is there for debugging, so empty global object suffices.

Comment: OK! I understand , now I edited the question a little bit, take a look....why in case of function return `this` is global object and when we simply log `this` it is empty object

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object):

> A global object is an object that always exists in the global scope.
>
> In JavaScript, there's always a global object defined. In a web
>   browser, when scripts create global variables, they're created as
>   members of the global object. (In Node.js this is not the case.) The
>   global object's interface depends on the execution context in which
>   the script is running. For example:
>
> In a web browser, any code which the script doesn't specifically start
>   up as a background task has a Window as its global object. This is the
>   vast majority of JavaScript code on the Web. Code running in a Worker
>   has a WorkerGlobalScope object as its global object. Scripts running
>   under Node.js have an object called global as their global object.

In window (browser) if you'll run:

```
console.log(this === window)
```

it will print `true` while if you'll run in node REPL:

```
this === global
```

it will return `true`